# Ansible loops and Azure resource dependencies

Tags: azure, ansible

I'm using Ansible to provision resources to Azure. I'd like to have one task for each type of resource I want to deploy to Azure which loops through a list of dictionaries, so I can just add more dicts in case I want more resources provisioned. I'd like to define each resource variable only once.

The problem that arises with this is dependencies to other resources. Resource groups need to be provisioned before virtual networks, virtual networks before subnets and so on. Yet the information of the top level resources is still needed when provisioning the bottom level ones.

Here's the first attempt, with all of the required top level resource vars defined in the bottom level resource vars as well:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:

    resourcegroups:
    - name: "eh_test_rg01"
      location: "westeurope"

    - name: "eh_test_rg02"
      location: "eastus"

   virtualnetworks:
   - name: "eh_test_vn01"
     cidr: 10.15.0.0/22
     resource_group: "eh_test_rg01"

   - name: "eh_test_vn02"
     cidr: 10.15.4.0/22
     resource_group: "eh_test_rg02"

    DMZ_subnets:
    - name: "eh_test_dmzsn01"
      cidr: 10.15.1.0/24
      vnet: "eh_test_vn01"
      location: "westeurope"
      resource_group: "eh_test_rg01"

    - name: "eh_test_dmzsn02"
      cidr: 10.15.5.0/24
      vnet: "eh_test_vn02"
      location: "eastus"
      resource_group: "eh_test_rg02"

    app_subnets:
    - name: "eh_test_appsn01"
      cidr: 10.15.2.0/24
      vnet: "eh_test_vn01"
      location: "westeurope"
      resource_group: "eh_test_rg01"

    - name: "eh_test_appsn02"
      cidr: 10.15.6.0/24
      vnet: "eh_test_vn02"
      location: "eastus"
      resource_group: "eh_test_rg02"

    gateway_subnets:
    - name: "GatewaySubnet"
      cidr: 10.15.0.0/24
      vnet: "eh_test_vn01"
      resource_group: "eh_test_rg01"
      location: "westeurope"

    - name: "GatewaySubnet"
      cidr: 10.15.4.0/24
      vnet: "eh_test_vn02"
      resource_group: "eh_test_rg02"
      location: "eastus"

  tasks:
  - name: Create resource Group
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      location: "{{ item.location }}"
    with_items:
     - "{{ resourcegroups }}"
    tags: resourcegroups

  - name: Create vnet
    azure_rm_virtualnetwork:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ item.resource_group }}"
      address_prefixes_cidr: "{{ item.cidr }}"
    with_items:
     - "{{ virtualnetworks }}"
    tags: vnets

  - name: Create subnets
    azure_rm_subnet:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ item.resource_group }}"
      address_prefix: "{{ item.cidr }}"
      virtual_network: "{{ item.vnet }}"
    with_items:
     - "{{ DMZ_subnets }}"
     - "{{ app_subnets }}"
     - "{{ gateway_subnets }}"
    tags: subnets
```

As can be seen from above example, by the subnets dicts there's already 2 vars I have defined before. The deeper we go into the hierarchy, the more excess dict entries will come into play.

I tried to build the relationships into the variable structure, but ran into issues looping though the new variable structure. With_subelements worked fine for looping two lists of dictionaries, but it can't handle 3 or more.

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:

    resourcegroups:
    - name: "eh_test_rg01"
      location: westeurope
      virtualnetworks:
      - name: "eh_test_vn01"
        cidr: 10.15.0.0/22
        subnets:
        - name: GatewaySubnet
          cidr: 10.15.0.0/24
        - name: eh_test_dmzsn01
          cidr: 10.15.1.0/24
        - name: eh_test_appsn01
          cidr: 10.15.2.0/24

    - name: "eh_test_rg02"
      location: westeurope
      virtualnetworks:
      - name: "eh_test_vn02"
        cidr: 10.15.4.0/22
        subnets:
        - name: GatewaySubnet
          cidr: 10.15.4.0/24
        - name: eh_test_dmzsn02
          cidr: 10.15.5.0/24
        - name: eh_test_appsn02
          cidr: 10.15.6.0/24
  tasks:
  - name: Create resource Group
    azure_rm_resourcegroup:
      name: "{{ item.name }}"
      location: "{{ item.location }}"
    with_items:
     - "{{ resourcegroups }}"
    tags: resourcegroups

  - name: Create vnet
    azure_rm_virtualnetwork:
      name: "{{ item.1.name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ item.0.name }}"
      address_prefixes_cidr: "{{ item.1.cidr }}"
    with_subelements:
     - "{{ resourcegroups }}"
     - virtualnetworks
    tags: vnets

# Blows up at this point, with_subelements does not support more lists than 2
  - name: Create subnets
    azure_rm_subnet:
      name: "{{ item.2.name }}"
      resource_group: "{{ item.0.name }}"
      address_prefix: "{{ item.2.cidr }}"
      virtual_network: "{{ item.1.vnet }}"
    with_subelements:
     - "{{ resourcegroups }}"
     - virtualnetworks
     - subnets
    tags: subnets
```

What would be the best way to approach this problem? Do I need to define the vars differently, make some kind of helper tasks to create variable structures before running the task itself, use different loops or..?

As far as I know, I can't make references to other dict values which are contained in a list of dictionaries using YAML.

Answer (score 0):

I would go totally other route and use arm templates, that a much better way of provisioning things on Azure, you can use native Ansible tasks for that as well:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/azure_rm_deployment_module.html

Comment: ARM templates are Azure spesific and Azure is not the only public cloud I work with, even if AWS has similiar stuff with their CloudFormation.

I've used azure_rm_deployment to deploy resources such as gateways and LB's before and the way I see it they don't remove the horizontal scaling problem of the resource types. When used with Ansible, you still have to specify the absolute path ("id" in azure) to the resource or utilize the Azure resource lookups in a way unknown to me.

Comment: so whats up with arm templates being azure specific? azure specific ansible tasks are not azure specific? O_o I don't know your exact scenario, but i'm pretty sure arm templates cover it.

Comment: Ansible tasks are Azure spesific, but Ansible itself isn't. I'd like to have one tool to use with all of the cloud providers vs. learn the native tools of each cloud provider. Curious about TerraForm as well, just haven't had the time to look into it properly, but that's going a bit off topic.

Comment: well, you are out of luck, nothing can really provision all the resources in Azure without using native tools

Comment: I do realize that, but working out the original problem will also help with using Ansible + azure_rm_deployment. I can use the same variable structure, strip out all the excess of the ARM templates and basically work with only the "resources" section of the templates.